# Access 2000-Stop Auto Rounding

Tags: ms-access, rounding

I am working with a table that someone else designed. The field is designated as a number. I want to enter a 2 digit number with one decimal place. [Ex: 27.5]     The field is automatically rounding to the ones place with a 0 in the tenths place. (27.0) The field size doesn't matter, I have tried them all. I put in formatting and an input mask, however it still automatically rounds.

Comment: What is the field size in design view?

Comment: Byte, Integer, Long Integer, Decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the table definition.

If it's a Number, it can be an Integer (Byte, Integer, Long Integer) type or a Real (Single, Double, etc.)  The integers will always round. Also, if you are using a real type, the Decimal option may have an effect as well

Comment: ...but the decimal property affects only display, not the actual precision of the stored data.

Comment: Apparently I hadn't tried them all. As soon as I read the Single and Double in your post, I thought, yeah I saw those, but since I wanted a 3 digit number that wouldn't work. However, that is why I asked the question, because I was taking those titles to literally.

Comment: Thank you Code Slave. I was able to use Single for the field size(which allows for decimal precision to 7), 1 decimal place, and the input mask. Thank you for telling me that the INTEGERS will always round. That is what was really frustrating me, since I couldn't find anything stating that it was rounding.